# Python - search for string, copy until end of doc

Tags: python, regex

I am using python to open EML files one at a time, process them then move them to another folder. EML file contains an email message including the headers.

The first 35-40 lines of the EML are header info, followed by the actual email message. Since the amount of lines of the header changes, I cant just convert my EML file to a list and tell it:

```
print emllist[37:]
```

However, the beginning of the last line of the headers is always the same and begins with X-OriginalArrivalTime.

My goal is to parse my EML file, search for the line number X-OriginalArrivalTime is on and then split the EML into 2 strings, one containing the headers info and one containing the message.

I have been rereading the python re documentation, but I cant seem to come up with a good way to attack this.

Any help is greatly appreciated

thanks

lou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably avoid regex. How about:

```
msg = data.split('X-OriginalArrivalTime', 1)[1].split('\n', 1)[1]
```

Comment: Now, how would I put the top half into a string?

Comment: I also see I could use str.partition()... Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

The `re` module is not very good at counting lines. What's more, you probably don't need it to check for the contents of the start of a line. The following function takes the filename of the EML file as input and returns a tuple containing two strings: the header, and the message.

```
def process_eml(filename):
    with open(filename) as fp:
        lines = fp.readlines()

    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if line.startswith("X-OriginalArrivalTime"):
             break
    else:
        raise Exception("End of header not found")

    header = '\n'.join(lines[:i+1]) # Message starts at i + 1
    message = '\n'.join(lines[i+1:])

    return header, message
```

Answer (score 0):

After

```
match = re.search(r'(.*^X-OriginalArrivalTime[^\n]*\n+)(.*)$',
                  open('foo.eml').read(),
                  re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
```

`match.groups(1)` should contain the headers and `match.groups(2)` the email message's body. The [`re.DOTALL`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag causes `.` to match newlines.

Comment: when i ran print match.groups(1) after this, i saw the entire message and not just the headers.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it works with eml files, but python [has a module](http://docs.python.org/library/email.parser.html#email.parser.Parser.parse) to work with email files.

If that does not work, isn't it true that headers are split from message with an empty-line?

```
lines = fp.readlines()
header_end = lines.index('\n') # first empty line, I think it is the end of header.
headers = lines[:header_end]
message = lines[header_end:]
```

Comment: i tried lines = open('alarm.eml').readlines() header = lines.index('\n) print header but it gives me 35 and not the text... where would i go from here?

Comment: You showed in question that you know how to split a list so I thought I don't need to show that again :) Updated.

Answer (score 0):

That's right that it would be interesting to avoid a regex, but presently, since you want to dispatch the header and the message into TWO different strings, I think that **split()**, that eliminates the sequence on which the split is made, and **partition()**, that returns a tuple of **3** elements, do not fit for the purpose , so a regex keeps interest:

```
import re

regx = re.compile('(.+?X-OriginalArrivalTime\.[^\n]*[\r\n]+)'
                  '(.+)\Z',
                  re.DOTALL)

ss = ('blahblah blah\r\n'
      'totoro tootrototo \r\n'
      'erteruuty\r\n'
      'X-OriginalArrivalTime. 12h58 Huntington Point\r\n'
      'body begins here\r\n'
      'sdkjhqsdlfkghqdlfghqdfg\r\n'
      '23135468796786876544\r\n'
      'ldkshfqskdjf end of file\r\n')


header,message = regx.match(ss).groups()

print 'header :\n',repr(header)
print
print 'message :\n',repr(message)
```

result

```
header :
'blahblah blah\r\ntotoro tootrototo \r\nerteruuty\r\nX-OriginalArrivalTime. 12h58 Huntington Point\r\n'

message :
'body begins here\r\nsdkjhqsdlfkghqdlfghqdfg\r\n23135468796786876544\r\nldkshfqskdjf end of file\r\n'
```